# How to configure server(hosting) for laravel-backend and vue-fontend in same host

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have laravel-backend which only provide api and vue-fontend which connected with that laravel-backend api . It's works locally fine.
But how to configure them in a single(both in same) live server(also with single domain).

Font-end is SPA. i create the font-end using "vue init webpack-simple my-project" commend.

Comment: Explain the front end more, is it an spa or multipage app?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different port for your api

By doing this you can run both applciations on the same server and access them by specifing the port in the url.

If you don't want to use ports in the url itself, you can also use nginx (or apache i suppose) with reverse proxy to give a 'path' to that port (would also be cleaner)